# Replace key of a PHP array by the value of a constant with common name?

Tags: php, arrays, curl

The title may be sound confusing so here is the code to explain clearly.

I wrote the following code in a PHP script

```
    $options=array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://site2sms.com/userregistration_next.asp',
        CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://site2sms.com/UserRegistration_Next.asp',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31',
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post_fields)
    );
```

But, when the dump the array using `var_dump` function here is what I got

```
array (size=5)
  10002 => string 'http://site2sms.com/userregistration_next.asp' (length=45)
  10016 => string 'http://site2sms.com/UserRegistration_Next.asp' (length=45)
  10018 => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31' (length=108)
  47 => int 1
  10015 => string 'action=UserCreate&txtFullName=fdsf&genderCombo=Male&birth_day=2&birth_month=12&birth_year=2013&txtEmail=fdsf%40dssad&ProfessCombo=1&StateCombo=Delhi&txtMobileNum=4234&cityCombo=223&Submit=Register' (length=196)
```

Clearly, the value of constant `CURLOPT_URL` is replaced by `10002` in its dump. So, I replaced the original array by this

```
    $options=array(
        'CURLOPT_URL' => 'http://site2sms.com/userregistration_next.asp',
        'CURLOPT_REFERER' => 'http://site2sms.com/UserRegistration_Next.asp',
        'CURLOPT_USERAGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31',
        'CURLOPT_POST' => TRUE,
        'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS' => http_build_query($post_fields)
    );
```

to get this dump value

```
array (size=5)
  'CURLOPT_URL' => string 'http://site2sms.com/userregistration_next.asp' (length=45)
  'CURLOPT_REFERER' => string 'http://site2sms.com/UserRegistration_Next.asp' (length=45)


  'CURLOPT_USERAGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31' (length=108)
  'CURLOPT_POST' => boolean true
  'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS' => string 'action=UserCreate&txtFullName=fdsf&genderCombo=Male&birth_day=2&birth_month=12&birth_year=2013&txtEmail=fdsf%40dssad&ProfessCombo=1&StateCombo=Delhi&txtMobileNum=4234&cityCombo=485&Submit=Register' (length=196)
```

Now, I am getting an error `Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values`. So, How can I tweak the array so that dumping array shows constant name not value and when used with `curl_setopt_array` it should work nicely. I am looking for some function that can be used a step earlier than curl_setopt_array function so that it can make necessary changes to array. If it is not possible through PHP built in functions please suggest me how to create this function manually.

Comment: Note: I have raised this question out of curiosity. I am learning PHP these days

Comment: You could keep your string keys, but utilize [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant) for passing its keys to `_setopt`.

Comment: @mario How can I implement this in my array? Is there some built in functions for it or I should `for each` loop for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's even a compact way for that:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch,
    array_combine(
        array_map("constant", array_keys($options)),
        array_values($options)
    )
);
```

To explain this a little:

- [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant) converts a stringy constant name to its value
- [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) just extracts the keys from your $options array
- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) applys `constant` to each key, returning its value, but keeps the order of the now integer-key list
- [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) returns the indexed list of your $options values
- finally [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) remerges the both-still-in-order numeric keys with their values

Since you mostly need this for commanding [curl](http://php.net/curl), I'd also like to present a little alternative here. Not for the overall question, but the concrete task at hand.

I'm personally using a small [**hybrid/fluent wrapper** `curl.php`](http://sourceforge.net/p/php7framework/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/php7/curl.php) for such things. It's possibly often shorter than the array options approach:

```
$result =
    curl()
       ->URL('http://site2sms.com/userregistration_next.asp')
       ->REFERER('http://site2sms.com/UserRegistration_Next.asp')
       ->USERAGENT('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/')
       ->POST(true)
       ->POSTFIELDS(http_build_query($post_fields))
       ->exec();
```

Which reduces all the `curl_` function and `CURL_` constant prefixes.
(But it still had `->setopt_array()` available, btw.)

Comment: This is an accident waiting to happen! If used inside a class, it will prefer a method named "constant" to the global function.

Comment: @EugenRieck I'm not sure I've ever seen array_map call up a method without passing `[$this,'method']`.

Comment: Just try it out, inside a class, where a method has the same name as a global function. Verified on PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch right now. (I was bitten by this in the past ...)

Comment: @EugenRieck Seriously, you have to show me. Can't reproduce it with either 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8+suhosin, 5.4.8, 5.5.5, 5.2.2, 5.1.0, 5.0.5 or 4.4.7.

Comment: Don't know how this will format: <?php
define('FOO_CONST','BAR-NAME');
class foo {
function constant($name) {return "foo-name";} 
function test() {return constant('FOO_CONST');}
}
echo foo::test();
?> outputs 'foo-name'

Comment: @mario Man you are really genius. The seconds code really beautiful.

Comment: @EugenRieck I'm still getting `BAR-NAME`, unless I specifically use `self::constant`, w/ or wo/ array_map. There must be something else in your setup.

Comment: This is a plain vanilla Ubuntu Precise box, nothing fancy, I ran exactly the code I posted ... very strange. Also in the past I had the same problem in a project, this must have been even older PHP.

Comment: I too got `BAR-NAME` along with a message `Strict standards: Non-static method foo::test() should not be called statically` using PHP 5.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example dump function for this. Pass it the array and a prefix of the constants it'll use for the map.

```
<?php

function const_keyed_array_dump($arr, $const_prefix) {
        static $map = array();

        // Primative caching
        if (!$map) {
                foreach (get_defined_constants() as $name=>$val) {
                        if (strpos($name, $const_prefix) === 0) {
                                $map[$val] = $name;
                        }
                }
        }

        $output = array();

        foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
                $output[$map[$key]] = $val;
        }

        return $output;
}

var_dump(
        const_keyed_array_dump(
                array(
                        CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE => 'foo',
                        CURLFTPSSL_TRY => 'bar',
                ),
                'CURL'
        )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

`CURLOPT_URL` (without quotes) is just another name for the integer `10002` - the moment you use it, it is translated. This is a one-way process!

If you want to use the string representation, you need either interims table:

```
$dumpableoptions=array(
    'CURLOPT_URL' => 'http://site2sms.com/userregistration_next.asp',
    ...
);

$translations=array(
    'CURLOPT_URL' => CURLOPT_URL,
    ...
);
```

and later

```
$options=array();
foreach ($dumpableoptions as $key=>$value)
  $options[$translations[$key]]=$value;
```

or you have to make use of the horror of horrors: `eval()`. I am not willing to provide code for that.

**EDIT**

After reading @mario's comment, I found out, that after developing in PHP since version 2 I still have lots to learn! I simply didn't know the `constant()` function. This changes a lot:

- forget the interims table, it is inside the cURL extension
- change the later code to

.

```
$options=array();
foreach ($dumpableoptions as $key=>$value)
  $options[constant($key)]=$value;
```

Comment: @mario again got another advanced way for that.

Comment: @VarunAgw And as I commented there, it has a big disadvantage!